# Read the content of a data file into memory into appropriate arrays of objects

Tags: java, string, io, text-files

So i am working on something to read the data from the file below and store the data into arrays of objects, so that i can search through those arrays.

```
YEAR,FIRST,SECOND,THIRD,FOURTH,GRAND-FINAL-PLAYED,WINNING-SCORE,LOSING-SCORE,CROWD
1908,Souths,Easts,Souths,Cumberland,Y,14,12,4000 
1909,Souths,Balmain,Souths,Wests,N 
1910,Newtown,Souths,Newtown,Wests,Y,4,4,14000 
1911,Easts,Glebe,Glebe,Balmain,Y,11,8,20000
1912,Easts,Glebe,Easts,Wests,N
```

As you can see the grand final is not played every year so some arrays for the score and crowd will be left blank.
Im confused like nothing else and just cant seem to do this. This is my code so far below and as you can see its nothing too flash so any help is apprciated.

```
String file ="data.txt";        

//reading   
try{
    InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(file); 
    InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);


    String line;
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){



        int commaIdx = 0;

        commaIdx = line.indexOf(",", commaIdx);

        int arrayIdx = 0;
        int beginIdx = 0;
        int lineNum = 1;

        String[] array1 = null;
        array1[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array2 = null;
        array2[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array3 = null;
        array3[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array4 = null;
        array4[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array5 = null;
        array5[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array6 = null;
        array6[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array7 = null;
        array7[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array8 = null;
        array8[lineNum] =" ";

        String[] array9 = null;
        array9[lineNum] =" ";


            while (commaIdx > 1)
            {
                String theValue = line.substring(beginIdx, commaIdx - 1);
                switch (arrayIdx)
                {
                case 1:
                    array1[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    array2[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    array3[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    array4[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    array5[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    array6[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    array7[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    array8[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    array9[lineNum] = theValue;
                    break;
                }


        arrayIdx++;
        beginIdx = commaIdx + 1;
        commaIdx = line.indexOf(",", commaIdx+1);

    }



    lineNum++;
    }
    br.close(); 

}       
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Since this is a CSV, why don't you use a CSV parsing library such as OpenCSV?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must be intanciated! You need to know the size of it beforehand:

```
String[] array1 = new String[size];
```

Comment: `arrayIdx` is 0, your switch ranges from 1 to 9, so nothing is ever done. Also you should really look a `String.split()`, it's a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` method, using commas as separator. Should work without any effort. Then just check the size of the return array to know if the grand final was played or not.

You can also use `StringTokenizer` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array1 = null;
```

That's where your problem is, you have to instanciate the array with the number of data you want them to hold.
If you don't know that number, you can use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

I think you will also find the `String.split(regex)` method usefull since allow you to create an array of string by splitting it using the given separator, like this:

```
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    String[] array = line.split(",");
```

Finaly, you'll get a lot of problem if your file have more than 9 lines, since you're using only 9 arrays. You should use a structure to hold your arrays, without naming them:

```
List<String[]> listOfArray = new LinkedList();
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    listOfArray.add(line.split(","));
}
```

This pretty much do what you want. To use one of the array:

```
String[] array = listOfArray.get(IndexOfTheArray);
```